# include file, arquivo não encontrado

Tags: php

Quando se faz uso de `include()` ou `include_once()`, e por alguma desventura o arquivo não é encontrado, então é revelado o nome do arquivo que falta e a estrutura de diretório.

Na própria documentação do php não há referência de tratar a informação quando o arquivo declarado não é encontrado, o que tenho feito foi fazer o uso de `@` antes do `include` para ocultar a mensagem mas não sei se isso é o correto ou algum tipo de "gambiarra", alguém tem alguma informação a respeito disso que possa compartilhar?

**EDITADA:**

Pesquisando mais a fundo encontrei a referência para "Operadores de controle de erro" que tirou minha dúvida, fica o link para que seja útil aos interessados.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

- Cabe ao manipulador de erros dar algum significado nos diferentes níveis de erro. Você pode fazer com que seu manipulador de erro personalizado faça eco de todos os erros, mesmo que o relatório de erros esteja definido como NONE.
- então o que o operador @ faz? Define temporariamente o nível de relatório de erros como 0 para essa linha. Se essa linha acionar um erro, o manipulador de erro ainda será chamado, mas será chamado com um nível de erro de 0

Comment: E lembre-se sempre de olhar o log de erros do PHP (ou do apache, por exemplo). Muitos dos erros que não são indicados na tela ainda aparecem lá. Atualizei os links

Comment: Li com paciencia e estou notando uma nova carga de conhecimento com tanto conteudo rico em detalhes, estou apaixonado por tudo isso. Gratidão.